# Possible Path in a 2D grid

Tags: analysis

Ravi is standing at point $(a,b)$ in an infinite 2D grid. He wants to know if he can reach point $(x,y)$ or not. The only operation he can do is to move to point $(a+b,b)$, $(a,a+b)$, $(a-b,b)$, or $(a,a-b)$ from some point $(a,b)$. It is given that he can move to any point on this 2D grid, i.e., the points having positive or negative X(or Y) co-ordinates.
Tell Ravi whether he can reach $(x,y)$ or not.

Comment: If he weren't able to reach some specific point, the question will become dependent on $x,y$ and become invalid for a true\false question. Hence he can (probably) reach any point.

Comment: I guess it is dependent on $(x,y)$.

Comment: One hint: if $(x,y)$ is reachable by these steps from $(a,b)$ then $\ \gcd(x,y)=\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Something odd is happening. For the first 3 moves, you're simply increasing the $x$-coordinate by $b$, increasing the $y$-coordinate by $a$, or decreasing the $x$-coordinate by $b$. But for the 4th, the $y$-coordinate is being changed by $2b - a$. Is $(a, a -  b)$ really the 4th move, or should it be $(a, b - a)$ ?

Comment: a,b,x & y are given by the user.So, based on the values given we need to check whether he can reach or not.?